# Exporting clips with Sync Points in ProTools

Tags: pro-tools

Can anyone shed some light on this one?

ProTools can't seem to export .bwavs with a sync point embedded, but occasionally I will get a clip from someone else that *will* have one on it, and when I look at it in the workspace browser it's 'Duration' is set to a Bars|Beats as opposed to time in seconds.

However, when I try copying (not exporting) one of these .wav files to another ProTools rig the sync point is not present..

As an experiment I dug out Cool Edit and tried putting in Cue markers .. loops, etc, and still couldn't get ProTools to recognize any of these on import.

It's always seemed like a really rudimentary function that appears to be missing... Or am I missing something?

James

Comment: wow, you're going deep here. Eager to see the answers -

Comment: Do you receive those clips as wav files or do you import them as session data? I did some test between H4n marks that are readable by Audition but not by ProTools. Last one seems doesn´t import this metadata.

Comment: Hi - as .wav 's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never known to be able to embed sync points and loop markers in the metadata of a file exported out of Pro Tools.  The only software that I have found to reliably make loop points is SoundForge.

Many game engines rely on loop points to create start-idle-stop sounds for weapons and vehicles.  I have always had to take my sound out of ProTools and into SoundForge to place markers and loop points in the file.  If you re-import those files back into ProTools the software ignores that metadata and does not recognize the markers or loop points.

Comment: Yeah it's hit and miss, but I definitely have some .wavs come in with sync points embedded

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to answer this question.

I think what you are trying to do is "timestamp" a file. Try this: Pull a file into PT and click on it so that it is highlighted. Go to the drop down menu of your audio bin (far upper right on the edit page). look for Time Stamp (shift+command+M  if you are on mac). A dialogue box should appear called User Time Stamp. It will show the name of the file at the top and at the very bottom the position of the file along the timeline. Next to it is an arrow. if you click on that arrow it will move the timecode position of the file to the top field. Timecode numbers will go from 00:00:00:00.00 to what ever the timecode of the file is.

Now your file is Time Stamped. But this Time Stamped sync value that you have assigned the audio file is (at its current state) is only readable by protools..... In order to embed the sync point or Time Stamp into the file so that it is readable by all applications you must then do this.

Again with the audio file highlighted click on the audio bin dropdown menu. Scroll down to Export Region Definitions (shift+command+Y  on mac). This will promt a dialogue box that explains the whole thing.

Now your Sync Point- or Time Stamp information is embedded into the file and readable by any application.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you run into any trouble

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this work for you? It doesn't for me unfortunately. I had tried exporting region definitions in the past but with no joy either. I'm on 8.0.3

Can you confirm that this is what should be done in order for it to work:

Timestamp the clip, then define sync point, select clip and export region definitions, then export clip to .wav

?

Cheers
J

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't want to embed timecode information, just the sync point (command+,)

Comment: Embed a sync point huh? Sync points are for spotting a region in a pro tools session. 

Also anytime you export a file you are creating new media. So you got me? Embedding a "sync point" on an audio file (or clip as you like to call it) is a Time Stamp- or maybe I am mis understanding you altogether??



Comment: Have you been able to export a Clip with a sync point like this? Can you re-import it and have the sync point visible? To put this in tangible terms : eg. a Door Close where the sync point is on the transient of the close.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this link can help http://www.showmeprotools.com/using-sync-points/

Comment: I can't see anything there about exporting them?

Answer (score 1):

Chris is correct , which is why I keep him around (lol). We have gone through scenarios where only Sound Forge sync point and loop markers would be recognized by the game engine. For instance, I have had several different Wavelab loop markers and sync points be ignored, but I am sure it depends on the particular engine you are implementing into.

Has anyone hear had good success with Wavelab marker and sync points? If so, what engine were you having those be recognized by?

Anyways, get Sound Forge. I cant live without it anymore!

Comment: Thanks Tom, and Chris.... it's a shame. I don't really need it badly enough to change programs though. J

Answer (score 1):

I´ve founded this webpage that talks a bit about exporting region properties to parent files. I´ve tried "Exporting Region Definition" a region that has sync point. When importing this audio files, sync point is imported too.

http://www.editorsguild.com/v2/magazine/Newsletter/pt-quicksd.html#sync_points

Comment: Hi there  --  I found this site a little while ago and it's what piqued my interest in this again!.. Alas, either I am still missing some detail or this particular feature has been removed since the writing of the article (which was in 1996 ?!)

I just tried again, but with no luck. Although ProTools is properly embedding the region definitions in to the parent file, it doesn't seem to do the same with the sync point (any more?). Thanks anyway.